# Resetting CLASSPATH after doing export CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classpath

I was trying to do a

```
setenv CLASSPATH /somethig/foo/junit-4.9.jar
```

kind of thing. After doing some searching (the command setenv was not detected). I found that I had to use instead

```
export CLASSPATH=/folder/junit-4.9.jar
```

Which didn't mark an error or anything. The problem is that it seemed to mess up other things that used to work like if I do

```
javac -Xlint FooTest.java
```

it says something like

> cannot find symbol variable Foo

```
Foo.start()
```

Foo comes from Foo.java and Foo.class files

And before doing the export classpath thing I was able to do this. Is there anyway to revert that?

**Where do I erase what i just added by doing the export CLASSPATH= bla bla?**

**I want to return to "the way things were" before I started adding the junit path**

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
if I do an echo of the value I get:

```
echo $CLASSPATH .:/folder/junit-4.9.jar:/junit-4.9.jar
```

Nevermind I erased the whole thing I put by setting CLASSPATH="" and now the stuff compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use,

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:/folder/junit-4.9.jar
```

Comment: I just want to erase the path that I added for junit-4.9.jar and compile everything as I had it before

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to rebuild your classpath again as the old one has overwritten by `export CLASSPATH=/folder/junit-4.9.jar`. Remember including the old classpath when you setting a new one:

```
export CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:/folder/junit-4.9.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
`export CLASSPATH=/folder/junit-4.9.jar:$CLASSPATH`
So you will have the old value of classpath plus new value.

if you really want to revert it, you can store it in a temp variable
`export TMP_CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH`
then
`export CLASSPATH=/folder/junit-4.9.jar`
then
`export CLASSPATH=$TMP_CLASSPATH`

Comment: but I already did the changes, I mean I can't save it in a temp variable anymore. A file that used to compile now does not compile after I attempted on adding the junit-4.9.jar classpath

Comment: New terminal should preserve the old environment, so you could logout and login / open a new terminal...